# How to handle Json data that is sometimes return in an array of objects and sometimes just an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting some Json from the server that I loop through to dynamically build a table in the dom.
When there are more than one objects the data is returned as an array of objects 
like this:

```
{
    "ProductList": {
        "Products": [{
            "ProductID": "1",
            "Name": "ProdName"},
        {
            "ProductID": "2",
            "Name": "ProdName2"}]
    }
}
```

however when there is only one object it is returned simply as an object and not an array like this:

```
{
    "ProductList": {
        "Products": {
            "ProductID": "3",
            "Name": "ProdName3"
        }
    }
}
```

So what I have been doing is checking if it is an array like this:

```
if ($.isArray(productDetails.ProductList.Products) === true) {
    for (i = 0; i < productDetails.ProductList.Products.length; i++) {
      //Create the dom elements by accessing the object properties with [i]
      //ie. productDetails.ProductList.Products[i].ProductsID
    }
}
else {
   //Create the dom elements by accessing the object properties w/o [i]
   //ie. productDetails.ProductList.Products.ProductsID
}
```

It works but I have a lot of code that is exactly the same except for the way the object properties are accessed and whenever I change one i need to remember to change the other or I will have problems. 
On the client side is their a better way to handle this?

Comment: isn't it better to return the the child object as an array no matter if it's 1 or multiple objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about converting `products` to array if it's not?

```
var products = productDetails.ProductList.Products;
if (!$.isArray(products)) {
    products = new Array(products);
}

... all logic here
```

Comment: This is pretty much how I used to handle a webservice whose JSON output was just converted from XML.

Answer (score 3):

... create a function?

```
 function maybeArray(obj, func) {
    if ($.isArray(obj))
      $.each(obj, func);
    else
      func(0, obj);
 }

 ...

 maybeArray(productDetails.ProductList.Products, function(i, product) {
    create DOM element for `product`;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it always an array.

```
if(!$.isArray(productDetails.ProductList.Products)){
  productDetails.ProductList.Products = [productDetails.ProductList.Products];
}
```